# Find key and then replace value

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects

```
  let attendanceGroup =  [
    0: {-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr: "absent"}
    1: {-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD: "absent"}
    2: {-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8: "absent"}
    3: {-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq: "absent"}
    ]

let membersPresent = [
0: {uid: -Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8}
1: {uid: LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq}
]
```

I need to find the key of let's say `-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD` then I need to change the "absent" to present.

I tried to just do a foreach and then enter the uid which is the key in each one.
Here I loop some other data membersPresent and then pull out a matching uid, which I need to change to present.

```
membersPresent.forEach(present => {
  attendanceGroup[present.uid] = 'present';
})
```

This doesn't work.  Any ideas how I can accomplish finding the key and then changing value from present to absent?

Comment: What is `attendanceGroup` (and `membersPresent`)?

Comment: just added them to the question @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `array.map`

**Direct Search**

```js
const searchKey = '-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD';
const data = [
    {'-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr': "absent"},
    {'-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD': "absent"},
    {'-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8': "absent"},
    {'-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq': "absent"}
];  
data.map(item => {
    item[searchKey]? item[searchKey] = 'present': ''
})
console.log(data);
```

If you are trying to compare the lost from an another array, choose this method.

1. Parse through the main array.
2. Check for each item in the array for the existence in the membersPresent array.
3. If the search item is present, replace it.

```js
const membersPresent = [
    {uid: '-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8'},
    {uid: 'LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq'}
]
const data = [
    {'-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr': "absent"},
    {'-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD': "absent"},
    {'-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8': "absent"},
    {'-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq': "absent"}
];  
data.map(item => {
    const dataItem = membersPresent.find(eachitem => eachitem.uid === Object.keys(item)[0])
    if(dataItem) {
        item[Object.keys(item)[0]] = 'present';
    }
})
console.log(data);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let attendanceGroup = [
    {"-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr": "absent"},
    {"-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD": "absent"},
    {"-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8": "absent"},
    {"-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq": "absent"}
]

let membersPresent = [
    {uid: "-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD"},
    {uid: "-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq"}
]

membersPresent.forEach(present => {
    let uid = present.uid; // User id of member who is present
    // Search the user in attendanceGroup
    for(let idx in attendanceGroup){ // idx is index of element i.e. 0,1,2,3,etc.
        let member = attendanceGroup[idx]; // member from attendanceGroup. Ex {"-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr": "absent"}
        if(uid in member) // Check if member id is same as given User id
            attendanceGroup[idx][uid] = 'present'; // mark present
    }
})

console.log(attendanceGroup)
```

Output

```
[ { '-Lwk9gsgfsQHkUljyyr': 'absent' },
  { '-Lwk98aagfaFTu0qNFJD': 'present' },
  { '-Lwk9BgBg05SygiRPKw8': 'absent' },
  { '-LwkasdfgHHCHw9e-3vq': 'present' } ]
```